# Click an image to change a text and another image on the site

Tags: javascript, html

[image]Im new to JS so I need a little help here.

I'm building a website in html where I have 3 pictures working as buttons.

- When I click picture 1 I want text1 plus image1 to show up.
- When I click picture 2 I want text2 plus image2 to show up.
- When I click picture 3 I want text3 plus image3 to show up.

The text is working for me right now so:
When I click picture 1 text1 is showing up on the site.

So I need help to add the pictures.

Here is my codes:

```js
function changeText(value) {
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var text = "";
    var image = "";

    if (value == 1) text += "this is picture one";
    if (value == 2) text += "this is picture two";
    if (value == 3) text += "this is picture tree";

    div.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<a href="javascript: changeText(1);">
   <img id="searchconsumers" src="images/search.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);">
   <img id="exploreconsumers" src="images/explore.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);">
   <img id="funconsumers" src="images/fun.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: What you mean by _image1, image2 .._ ?

Comment: I want image1, image2, image3 to show up. So I click button 1 and I want text1 and image1 to show up. If I click button 2 I want text2 and image 2 to show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this ?

```js
function changeText(value) {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var text = "";
  var image = "";

  if (value == 1) text += "this is picture one <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/1.png'/>";
  if (value == 2) text += "this is picture two <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/2.png'/>";
  if (value == 3) text += "this is picture tree <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/3.png'/>";

  div.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.custom_h_w{
  top: 120px;
  right: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: changeText(1);">
   <img id="searchconsumers" src="images/search.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);">
   <img id="exploreconsumers" src="images/explore.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);">
   <img id="funconsumers" src="images/fun.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that was what I was looking for. thank you. One more thing. How do I position and adjust width and height for the img src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/1.png'?

Comment: Hi, you could add a custom class to your css and attach it with the img tags `<img class="custom_w_h" .../>`.

Comment: hi, so i will end up having a code in css like this: <img class="'xerys.com/images/xerys/1.png" top="2000px" right="100px"/>

this can't be right i guess? thanks

Comment: Thats so awesome. Thanks a lot. To position the text (this is picture 1) can I add a "var position" to JS?

Answer (score 0):

This is What are You expecting??

```js
function changeText(value) {
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    var text = "";
    var image = "";

    if (value == 1) {
    document.getElementById("searchconsumers").style.cssText="transform: scale(2); transition: all 1s linear"; 
        document.getElementById("exploreconsumers").style.cssText="transform: scale(1);transition: all 1s linear"; 
    document.getElementById("funconsumers").style.cssText="transform: scale(1);transition: all 1s linear"; 

    text += "this is picture one";
     div.innerHTML = text;
     
      
    }
    if (value == 2){
     document.getElementById("searchconsumers").style.cssText="transform: scale(1);transition: all 1s linear"; 
        document.getElementById("exploreconsumers").style.cssText="transform: scale(2);transition: all 1s linear"; 
    document.getElementById("funconsumers").style.cssText="transform: scale(1);transition: all 1s linear"; 
    text += "this is picture two";
     div.innerHTML = text;}
    if (value == 3) {
       document.getElementById("searchconsumers").style.cssText="transform: scale(1);transition: all 1s linear"; 
        document.getElementById("exploreconsumers").style.cssText="transform: scale(1);transition: all 1s linear"; 
    document.getElementById("funconsumers").style.cssText="transform: scale(2);transition: all 1s linear"; 
    text += "this is picture tree";
     div.innerHTML = text;}

   
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


<a href="javascript: changeText(1);">
   <img id="searchconsumers" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/supersmashbrosfanon/images/9/91/SSB4_-_Pikachu_Artwork.png/revision/latest?cb=20150727015314" width="40px" height="40px" alt="test1" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);">
   <img id="exploreconsumers" src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120906164108/fantendo/images/e/ee/Super_Mushroom_for_tlotll.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="test2" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);">
   <img id="funconsumers" src="http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/small-super-mario.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="test3" />
</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="div"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

```js
function a(value) {
    if (value == 1) {
    document.getElementById("image1").style.cssText="display:block";
          document.getElementById("image2").style.cssText="display:none";     
    document.getElementById("image3").style.cssText="display:none";     

  }
 if (value == 2) {
    document.getElementById("image1").style.cssText="display:none";
          document.getElementById("image2").style.cssText="display:block";     
    document.getElementById("image3").style.cssText="display:none";     

  }
   if (value == 3) {
    document.getElementById("image1").style.cssText="display:none";
          document.getElementById("image2").style.cssText="display:none";     
    document.getElementById("image3").style.cssText="display:block";     

  }
}
```

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}
#image1,#image2,#image3{
display:none;
}
#main1{
display:inline-block;
}
input[type="submit"] {
background: #0066A2;
color: white;
border-style: outset;
border-color: #0066A2;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
font: bold 15px arial, sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<div id="main1">
<input type="submit" value="pika" onclick="a(1)">
    <br/> <br/>
<a href="javascript: changeText(1);">
    <div id="image1">
   <img id="searchconsumers" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/supersmashbrosfanon/images/9/91/SSB4_-_Pikachu_Artwork.png/revision/latest?cb=20150727015314" width="40px" height="40px" alt="test1" />
    <p>This is image1</p>
    </div>
</a>
  </div>
    
    
    <div id="main1">
    <input type="submit" value="muss" onclick="a(2)">
    <br/> <br/>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);">
    <div id="image2">
   <img id="exploreconsumers" src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120906164108/fantendo/images/e/ee/Super_Mushroom_for_tlotll.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="test1" />
    <p>This is image2</p>
    </div>
</a>
      </div>
    
    
    <div id="main1">
    <input type="submit" value="mario" onclick="a(3)">
    <br/> <br/>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);">
    <div id="image3">
   <img id="funconsumers" src="http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/small-super-mario.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="test1" />
    <p>This is image3</p>
    </div>
</a>
  </div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't want the buttons to change - but this is actually also a cool feature. What I want is when I click button1,  image1 and text 1 show up . (image1 and button 1 is not the same image)

Comment: ok but you havent created a button in your code, so i thought of doing this

Comment: yeah I know. I just use the image. So when the image is click a new image is showing up on the site. - But I can't figure that part out.

Comment: Is this code fine for You or you need a button click

Comment: If you know how to make the button click I would appreciate if you could show it to me:

button1 is click and image1 and text1 will show up-

Comment: Do you want like this??

Comment: I have given my best @ThomasVarberg , i hope this will be ok , if not i am sorry

Comment: If it is OK tick the answer , it will be helpful for others

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Its almost working. For more clarification I have uploaded a picture that explains it.